# Assitance in List Value Extractions

Tags: python, pycharm

what I need right now is to extract a specific file
example:

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(List[1:2])
```

Output being [2]
what I need is exactly 2, and not [2]
To python in general, anything will help thanks

Comment: you can get the single element with List[1]

Comment: Then just use `List[1]`.  Also read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) which explains basics like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [2]: print(List[1])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are slicing an array OR list, it means you giving a range of index like `[1:5]` so, it must return a list. Better you can use single index of array OR list. Then it will return single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way to do this is to just print the value of what you want. I.E:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(list[1])
```

This will print out 2. I am confused on why you are looking in a range of the list which will output another list hence why you are getting [2]. I recommend going back and reading up on lists and what you can do to them in the python tutorials. Youtube might be a great help if your more visual as well. Best of luck

P.S. Remember that lists are 0 based and start at 0. Thus to get 2 in this list, you need to print out the 1 spot which is really the second spot in the list. 0 = 1, 1 = 2, 2 = 3, etc if you look at the list I created.